# pushnew without place support. Is it considered a destructive macro?

Tags: lisp

One function and one macro

```
;; I am sorry for the confusing function name.
;; As one answer suggests, cons-if-not-member is the better name.
(defun cons-if-member (element list)
  (if (member element list)
      list
    (cons element list)))

(defmacro pushnew-no-bells (element list)
  "pushnew without place support"
  `(setq ,list (cons-if-member ,element ,list)))

(let ((xx (list 1 2)))
  (pushnew-no-bells 0 xx)
  xx)
```

I do not know which of the following is correct:

1. cons-if-member is a non-destructive function and pushnew-no-bells is a destructive macro.
2. Both are non-destructive.
3. cons-if-member is a non-destructive function and the adjectives "destructive" and "non-destructive" do not apply to macros.
4. none of the above

I do not have any idea on whether pushnew is considered destructive or not either, but  I wanted to make things simple by dropping place support first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cons-if-member` is not destructive.  It is also roughly equivalent to [ADJOIN](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_adjoin.htm).  `pushnew-no-bells` modifies a place, but does not modify the structure of the list onto which an element might be pushed.  However, it can modify the structure of *other* lists, because you could use it  as `(let ((list (list 1 2 3 4))) (pushnew-no-bells '1 (cddr list)))`.  (Also, the form `list` will be evaluated twice, which is not good (but also not the main point of this question/answer).)   This is destructive in the sense that it modifies that place, but it is not destructive in the sense that, e.g., `nreverse` is (`nreverse` can change the entire structure of a cons list).

The Hyperspec doesn't make quite the same distinction between destructive and non-destructive.  The spec for ADJOIN, for instance, just says what it does

> Tests whether item is the same as an existing element of list. If the item is not an existing element, adjoin adds it to list (as if by cons) and returns the resulting list; otherwise, nothing is added and the original list is returned.

and omits any mention of side effects.  The documentation for [PUSHNEW](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/m_pshnew.htm#pushnew), on the other hand, mentions in its syntax section that it requires a place

> **pushnew** *item place &key key test test-not*
> => *new-place-value*

and the decription mentions that it has side effects:.

> the new list is **stored** in place. [emphasis added] …
>
> **Side Effects:**
>  The contents of place may be modified.

While destructive and non-destructive capture some general ideas about how things are implemented, actual implementations tend to be a little bit more subtle, because the programmer is concerned with *what* things might be destructively modified, and what sort of state might be changed.

The approach that you are using (that is, making a functional implementation of some operation and then implementing a modifying macro on top of it), however, is very good, as it will help you document what functions and macros will have side effects.  It will help anyone reading that documentation understand what the intended side effects of the macro is (just compute what the function would compute, and then store it back to the place).  If you're doing much of this (actually, if you're doing *any* of this), you should also probably take a good look at [DEFINE-MODIFY-MACRO](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defi_2.htm) which makes implementing these kinds of function/macro pairs very easy, and will help you avoid common pitfalls (like the double evaluation of `list` above).

Answer (score 3):

`pushnew` changes the value of it's place-form (2nd argument), so it is destructive: it changes something "in place" instead of just creating a new object (which may share structure with an existing one). Your `cons-if-member` (which would better be called `cons-unless-member` or `cons-if-not-member`) does not modify anything "in place", so it's actually non-destructive.

Note, BTW., that you cannot really exclude "general place" support, due to the presence of symbol macros. Observe:

```
(defclass foo ()
  ((x :initform nil)))

(let ((instance (make-instance 'foo)))
  (with-slots (x) instance
    (pushnew-no-bells 1 x))
  (format t "~&Now: ~S~%" (slot-value instance 'x)))
```