# Read a file into a list of pairs in elisp

Tags: list, emacs, lisp, elisp

I am trying to write an elisp function to read each word in a file into a pair. I want the first item of the pair to be the string sorted lexicographically, and the second item to be untouched.

Given the example file:

```
cat
cow
dog
```

I want the list to look like:

```
(act cat)
(cow cow)
(dgo dog)
```

My best crack at it is:

```
(defun get-file (filename)
  (with-open-file (stream filename)
    (loop for word = (read-line stream nil)
          while word
          collect ((sort word #'char-lessp) word))))
```

It compiles correctly in Emacs lisp interaction mode. However, when I try to
run it by executing

```
(get-file "~/test.txt")
```

I end up in the Emacs debugger, and it's not telling me anything useful . . .

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function get-file)
  (get-file "~/test.txt")
  eval((get-file "~/test.txt") nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(t)
  eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-print-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-print-last-sexp)
```

I am a lisp beginner, and have no idea what is wrong.

Thanks,

Justin

Answer (score 8):

#### Vanilla Emacs

First, let's use Emacs's built-in functions only. There's no built-in function to sort strings in Emacs, so you first should convert a string to a list, sort, then convert the sorted list back to a string. This is how you [convert a string to a list](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Lists.html#index-append):

```
(append "cat" nil) ; => (99 97 116)
```

A string converted to a list becomes a list of characters, and [characters are represented as numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Character-Codes.html#Character-Codes) in Elisp. Then you [sort](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rearrangement.html#index-sort) the list and [convert it to a string](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Strings.html#index-concat):

```
(concat (sort (append "cat" nil) '<)) ; => "act"
```

There's no built-in function to load file contents directly into a variable, but you can [load them](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Reading-from-Files.html#index-insert_002dfile_002dcontents_002dliterally) into a [temporary buffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Current-Buffer.html#index-with_002dtemp_002dbuffer). Then you can [return the entire temporary buffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Contents.html#index-buffer_002dsubstring_002dno_002dproperties) as a string:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert-file-contents-literally "file.txt")
  (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))
```

This will return the string `"cat\ncow\ndog\n"`, so you'll need to [split](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Strings.html#index-split_002dstring) it:

```
(split-string "cat\ncow\ndog\n") ; => ("cat" "cow" "dog")
```

Now you need to [traverse](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mapping-Functions.html#index-mapcar) this list and convert each item into a pair of sorted item and original item:

```
(mapcar (lambda (animal)
          (list (concat (sort (append animal nil) '<)) animal))
        '("cat" "cow" "dog"))
;; returns
;; (("act" "cat")
;;  ("cow" "cow")
;;  ("dgo" "dog"))
```

Full code:

```
(mapcar
 (lambda (animal)
   (list (concat (sort (append animal nil) '<)) animal))
 (split-string
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents-literally "file.txt")
    (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))))
```

#### Common Lisp Emulation

One of the Emacs built-in packages is [`cl.el`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/), and there's no reason not to use it in your code. Therefore I lied, when I said there is no built-in functions to sort strings and the above is the only way to do the task using built-in functions. So let's use `cl.el`.

[`cl-sort`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Sorting-Sequences.html#index-cl_002dsort) a string (or any [sequence](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequences-Arrays-Vectors.html#index-sequence)):

```
(cl-sort "cat" '<) ; => "act"
```

[`cl-mapcar`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Mapping-over-Sequences.html#index-cl_002dmapcar) is more versatile than Emacs's built-in `mapcar`, but here you can use either of them.

There is a problem with `cl-sort`, it is [destructive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17039756/596361), meaning it modifies the argument in-place. We use local variable `animal` inside the anonymous function twice, and we don't want to garble the original `animal`. Therefore we should pass a [copy](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequence-Functions.html#index-copy_002dsequence) of a sequence into it:

```
(lambda (animal)
  (list (cl-sort (copy-sequence animal) '<) animal))
```

The resulting code becomes:

```
(cl-mapcar
 (lambda (animal)
   (list (cl-sort (copy-sequence animal) '<) animal))
 (split-string
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents-literally "file.txt")
    (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))))
```

#### `seq.el`

In Emacs 25 a new sequence manipulation library was added, [`seq.el`](https://github.com/NicolasPetton/seq.el). Alternative to `mapcar` is `seq-map`, alternative to CL's `cl-sort` is `seq-sort`. The full code becomes:

```
(seq-map
 (lambda (animal)
   (list (seq-sort animal '<) animal))
 (split-string
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents-literally "file.txt")
    (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))))
```

#### dash, s, f

Usually the best solution to work with sequences and files is to reach directly for these 3 third-party libraries:

- [**`dash`**](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) for list manipulation
- [**`s`**](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) for string manipulation
- [**`f`**](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) for file manipulation.

Their Github pages explain how to install them (installation is very simple). However for this particular problem they are a bit suboptimal. For example, [`-sort`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-sort-comparator-list) from **`dash`** only sorts lists, so we would have to get back to our string->list->string conversion:

```
(concat (-sort '< (append "cat" nil))) ; => "act"
```

`s-lines` from **`s`** leaves empty strings in files. On GNU/Linux text files usually end with newline at the end, so splitting your file would look like:

```
(s-lines "cat\ncow\ndog\n") ; => ("cat" "cow" "dog" "")
```

`s-split` supports an optional argument to omit empty lines, but it's separator argument is a [regex](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression) (note that you need both `\n` and `\r` for [portability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)):

```
(s-split "[\n\r]" "cat\ncow\ndog\n" t) ; => ("cat" "cow" "dog")
```

Yet there are 2 functions which can simplify our code. [`-map`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-map-fn-list) is similar to `mapcar`:

```
(-map
  (lambda (animal)
    (list (cl-sort (copy-sequence animal) '<) animal))
  '("cat" "cow" "dog"))
;; return
;; (("act" "cat")
;;  ("cow" "cow")
;;  ("dgo" "dog"))
```

However in **`dash`** there are [anaphoric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphoric_macro) versions of functions that accept a function as an argument, such as `-map`. Anaphoric versions allow to use shorter syntax by exposing local variable as `it` and start with 2 dashes. E.g. the below are equivalent:

```
(-map (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) (1 2 3)) ; => (2 3 4)
(--map (+ it 1) (1 2 3)) ; => (2 3 4)
```

Another improvement is [`f-read-text`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-read-text-path-optional-coding) from **`f`**, which simply returns contents of a file as a string:

```
(f-read-text "file.txt") ; => "cat\ncow\ndog\n"
```

#### Combine best of all worlds

```
(--map (list (cl-sort (copy-sequence it) '<) it)
       (split-string (f-read-text "file.txt")))
```

Comment: Not sure why this is not an accepted answers. Can you do that @justinrixx?

Answer (score 1):

On my emacs, either <kbd>C-j</kbd> or <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> evaluates the form as you said. When I try to do the same with `(get-file "test")` the debugger complains about `with-open-file` being undefined. I cannot find `with-open-file` in `cl-lib` (or `cl`) emacs packages.
Did you require some other package? Also, I think the idiomatic way of opening file in Emacs is to temporary visit them in buffers. 
Anyway, if the code was Common Lisp it would be ok except for `collect ((sort ...) word)`, where you are *not* building a list but using `(sort ...)` in a function position. I'd use `(list (sort ...) word)` instead.

Comment: Well when I say it compiles I mean that if I press `CTRL`+`J` at the last line of the function in lisp interaction mode it outputs `get-file` on the next line. If that's not compiling though, I made a mistake.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't have a handle on what's specific to what dialect of lisp. I just modified the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813895/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-a-file-into-a-list-in-lisp)

Comment: @justinrixx It you want to code in Emacs Lisp, you have nothing to do. If you want to use Emacs to interact with Common Lisp, you have to setup Slime. Lisp dialects might look similar but they are not.